# how mobile app should interact with web api?

Tags: api, flutter, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am working on a flutter project that gets data from my .net core web API. it works fine but every time I load my screen or switch between tabs in the app it gets data(content and pictures) from my API, although I estimate that my data may be usually updating once or twice a week. I want to know what is the best performance solution for this situation.

I will be happy if I know the opinion or experience of others in this regard.
thank you.

Comment: Please read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: I want to know how apps like "calm" interact with server

Answer (score 1):

> it works fine but every time I load my screen or switch between tabs
> in the app it gets data(content and pictures) from my API, although I
> estimate that my data may be usually updating once or twice a week. I
> want to know what is the best performance solution for this situation.

Try to use F12 developer tools Performance panel to check which part of website need to improve the performance. Then, based on the result to do something.

Since the data are some content and pictures, you could consider using the following tips to improve the website performance:

1. **Avoid synchronous and use asynchronous**

   Try to avoid synchronous calling when developing ASP.NET Core 3.0 applications. Synchronous calling blocks the next execution until the current execution is completed. While fetching data from an API or performing operations like I/O operations or independent calling, execute the call in an asynchronous manner. Avoid using Task.Wait and Task.Result, and try to use await.
2. **Optimize data access**

   Most applications are totally dependent on a database. They have to fetch data from the database, process the data, and then display it. If it is time-consuming, then the application will take much more time to load.

   Recommendations:

   - Call all data access APIs asynchronously.
   - Don’t try to get data that is not required in advance.
   - Try to use no-tracking queries in Entity Framework Core when accessing data for read-only purposes.
   - Use filter and aggregate LINQ queries (with .Where, .Select, or .Sum statements), so filtering can be performed by the database.
3. **Use caching technology**

   Increase the performance of an application by reducing the number of requests to the server. Avoid calling the server every time and cache the data instead. Store the response for the future, and use it the next time you make a call for the same response.

   Reference: [Response caching in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and [use Response Caching Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/middleware?view=aspnetcore-3.1).
4. Reduce HTTP requests and use response compression
5. Client-side improvements

   Client-side optimization is one important aspect of improving performance, consider the following tips:

   - [Bundle and minify static assets in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification?view=aspnetcore-3.1)
   - Use thumbnail images.

Reference: [ASP.NET Core Performance Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/performance-best-practices?view=aspnetcore-3.1#cache-aggressively)

Comment: thanks a lot. I take a look at f12 tools but I want to know how should my frontend mobile app interact with my api.